# Can GIN or GIST be used for an "containing at least" comparison?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing

I am using the extension intarray for int comparisons with release 9.2.9.

While `&&` can use an index to filter arrays containing at least one value, is there a way to use a GIN or GIST index to filter arrays with at least n values intersecting?

For example, how can GIN or GIST use `2 <= icount(ARRAY[1,2,3] & int_array_column)` or `2 <= ARRAY_UPPER((ARRAY[1,2,3] & int_array_column),1)`?

Comment: Do the ARRAY[1,2,3] need to be dynamic ? Or do you always have these values [1,2,3] ?

Comment: Yes, the values unfortunately need to be dynamic.

Comment: Question isn't very clear ... You're trying to find all arrays containing at least n values, if I understand it correctly? (The `ARRAY[1,2,3] & int_array_column` is Ruby/Sequel's syntax to write what would simply be ARRAY[1,2,3] in plain SQL, right?)

Comment: Im trying to find a way to speed up an array intersects query that intersects on at least n values. `&` is the intarray extension function for array intersection. `icount(ARRAY[1,2,3] & int_array_column)` counts the number of values that intersect but requires a full table scan to find arrays matching on at least 2+ values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [smlar](http://sigaev.ru/git/gitweb.cgi?p=smlar.git;a=summary) extension by Teodor Sigaev has what im looking for. The `%` operator indexes on n intersecting values.

Answer (score 0):

A btree would be able to index your expression, then filter on the number of values that you need:

```
CREATE INDEX my_awesome_ids 
ON my_fat_table (icount(ARRAY[1,2,3] & int_array_column)); 

SELECT * 
FROM my_fat_table 
WHERE 2 <= (icount(ARRAY[1,2,3] & int_array_column));
```

Comment: The array would need to be dynamic, so this index unfortunately would not work.